# I want to use a column name in having clause without having that column in my view

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a sales table with the below details:

Address : xxx, yyy,zzzz, aaa, bbb

Price: null, null, 910000, 80000, null

Beds: 3,4,5,6,7

Type: Unit, House, Unit, Unit, House

Result: "Sold at auction", "passed In - No Bid", "Sold at auction", "Sold after auction" ...

daterecorded:  2017-11-21, 2017-11-25, 2017-11-25  and so on...

suburb: Denham Court, Alfords Point,Allambie Heights, and so on ...

I am trying to write an sql query to list the max number of bedrooms for houses in each suburb for properties that have a selling price. Order by the max number of bedrooms decending then by alphabetical
suburb name and exclude properties that dont list the number of bedrooms.

The code which i have tried is given below:

```
select suburb, max(beds)
from sales
group by suburb
having price is not null and max(bed) is not null
order by max(beds) desc, suburb asc
```

I am getting the below error:
Unknown column 'price' in 'having clause'.

I am confused as to how to use a column in "having" without showing them in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can't you use it in a where clause

```
SELECT 
    suburb, MAX(beds)
FROM
    sales
WHERE price IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY suburb
HAVING 
    MAX(bed) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY MAX(beds) DESC , suburb ASC;
```